# What stable browser will allow me to work productively in a business environment without crashing?

Tags: windows-7, browser

I have tried all of the basic families of browser: IE, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and all of them crash too frequently for my needs and are unacceptable. IE does this on random basis, Firefox everyday, Opera on multimedia content, and Chrome on interpreted dynamic content. Safari is too slow on windows.

The browser I seek may be distributed under EULA and be commercial, but I would require an estimated crash warranty in the licence.

Programing without warranty, a.k.a. GNU, is able most of kids.

Comment: If you observe crashing of **every** browser on your machine then something is wrong with your machine, not the browsers. On my machine I haven't seen IE and Firefox to crash yet, it's been running already for about 4 months...

Comment: Also, the second last line dosen't make sense to me. What does "is able most of kids" mean?

Comment: If this is very consistent then a particular site you are using could be the ones causing the issue.

Comment: estimated crash warranty?

Answer (score 2):

I use IE, FF, and Chrome daily on 3 separate machines, and none of them crash. So I'd guess the issue here is at OS level, or some plugin you might be using.

Answer (score 1):

The web is an evolving place, with an increasing number of standards, formats and protocols that must be supported in a browser that is suitable for all purposes.

As more features are required, complexity increases, and with it potential issues increase.  This is true of any software.  Where this is countered is with time and testing.  The more involved in both depth and duration your testing procedures, the more likely you are to identify and resolve issues prior to release.

With browsers, there are three main pressures

1. Features and standards support leadership
2. Speed
3. Stability

The big name browsers right now are in intense competition to achieve all three, and it is a delicate balancing act.  In order to achieve leadership in standards, features, and speed, you need to release.  You need to release before your competition.

This means to varying degrees, you have to allow a bit of flexibility with stability.  Each of the participants do this with varying degrees of success.  But as you have noted, they all have issues in different areas.  The landscape that describes these limitations is not static - with new releases, new issues will arise and old issues will be resolved.

You are after a bulletproof browser that is eternally stable, yet is general purpose enough to support dynamic content, multimedia, and is fast, and can render whatever the web might throw at it.  These very same pressures that cause issues with stability.

If you have mission critical aspects of your browsing workflow, then identify what they are and use the best browser to carry out those tasks individually.  Use the best tool for the task at hand, rather than seeking a single tool that meets all requirements.

Comment: do you honestly think that it isn't possible to build a browser in which the crash of part of the system won't result in cascading failure of the whole?

Comment: They all aim to do this, and increasingly in recent releases.